# Magento 2: Taxes are subtracted from the order total

Tags: magento2, checkout, tax-calculation

I have the following problem:

In the checkout the order total is incorrect, as the total price of the items and the shipping costs are subtracted from the total taxes.

All products include taxes.

[image: CHECKOUT EXAMPLE]

This is our tax configuration:
[image: This is our tax configuration:]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the setting like this into following 2 sections.

```
A. Shopping Cart Display Settings
B. Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display Settings
```

**Check this :** https://i.imgur.com/WbkfSFx.png

Comment: I've tried with your solution but the problem persists